# RegExp confusion

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Java concept of Regular expression.

Could anyone please tell me the correct regular expression that I should use for the below string -

`String exp =  "ABCD_123_abc".`

and the regular expression that I am using for the above string is:

`regExp = "([a-zA-Z]+)_([0-9]+)_([a-z]+)"`

But the output of the below code is `"**No Match Found**"`

```
Public static void main()
{
   String exp = "ABCD_123_abc";
   String regExp = "([a-zA-Z]+)_([0-9]+)_([a-z]+)";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(exp);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(regExp);
   if(matcher.matches())
   {
     System.out.println("Match found");
   }
   else
   {
     System.out.println(" NO Match found");
   }


}
```

Comment: Did you fix the code in your question after it was answered? That's confusing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is: you accidentally swapped the use of the regexp pattern and the expression to check

```
String exp = "ABCD_123_abc";
String regExp = "([a-zA-Z]+)_([0-9]+)_([a-z]+)";
```

Should be used

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(exp);
```

The [Pattern.compile(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29) function accepts the regular expression.

**EDIT**

I apologize, my first solution was truly something that must **never ever, *never* ever** be done: the names of the variables were contradictory to the meaning of their values... That means pain and tears, and getting hit by angry colleagues while being shouted at. And there is no valid defense to this **crime**...

**EDIT2**
You can get the individual matched groups by the [Matcher.group(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) function:

```
String matchedStringpart matcher.group(2);
```

Notice: I used `2` as the argument:

- `0` means the input sequence matched
- `1` means the first group (`ABC` in this case)
- ... and so on

If you only need the `123` part, I'd rewrite the regex for clarity:

```
regExp = "[a-zA-Z]+_([0-9]+)_[a-z]+";
```

However, in that case, the `group()` has to be called with `1`, as now the first (and only) matched group is the first one:

```
String matchedStringpart matcher.group(1);
```

Comment: I think, actually, `Pattern.compile(regExp)` makes better sense, which would mean OP reversed the compile and matcher statements, but essentially it's the same bug.

Comment: Solves it, but the names are now very misleading

Comment: @all True, Sometimes brains are quirky things :) I assumed that if the Strings have to be swapped, I can swap the handles to it (lazyness, this meant less characters to be changed) - somehow I completely ignored the semantics of the names of the variables. Which is not to be done at all times...

Comment: Thax alot for the solution.

Comment: +1 not for the answer, but for "there is no valid defense to this crime..." I wish more of my colleagues would respond to their own mistakes like this.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut +1 for your +1. Disclaimer: I did once, long time ago debug a variable named `isAvailable` _acting funny_.  I think, you can finish the story from here :) :)

Answer (score 8):

You're not compiling the regexp. You need

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(exp);
```

i.e. your above code is confusing the regexp and the input string. Your actual regexp is correct, however.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex is **perfectly fine**.

The problem comes from the fact that you swapped `exp` and `regExp` in your code. The function `compile` takes as argument a regular expression, whereas the function `matcher` takes the expression to match.

Answer (score 4):

Your (edited) regexp is fine.

If you want to extract `123`, you can use `matcher.group(2)`. That method can **only** be invoked **after** `matches` or `find`. `matcher.group(n)` returns the n-th `capture group`. A capture group is a part of your regexp that is enclosed in parentheses. `matcher.group(0)` returns the matched string.

Example

```
if(matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
  System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
}
```

prints

```
 ABCD_123_abc
 ABCD
 123
 abc
```

Answer (score 2):

`if(exp.matches(regExp))`

This alone is enough. You don't need a Pattern/Matcher unless you've some other needs.

Answer (score 1):

In this case if you want to retrieve 123 use the following code :

```
 System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

This prints output as : **123**

Your regex is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will work - it matches any number of upper or lower case letter then an underscore then any number of digits then an underscore then any number of upper or lower case letters. If you want to be more specific you can use `{n}` rather than `+` to match a specific number of characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String myString = "ABCD_123_abc";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]++_(\\d++)_[A-Za-z]++$");
    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(myString);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First compile the regular expression then compare it using matcher..

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(exp);
```